# working sample of fluent nhibernate with second level cache

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NHibernate L2 Cache configuration in Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020730/nhibernate-l2-cache-configuration-in-fluent-nhibernate)

i can't find a working simple sample of second level caching with fluent nhibernate.

if u found one please give me link.

Comment: I had the same question and found the answer, see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020730/nhibernate-l2-cache-configuration-in-fluent-nhibernate/2029224#2029224) AWC